# track emails that are sent from a case using workflow

Tags: apex, email, workflow, case

I'm having a workflow to send an email on satisfying certain criteria on the case object. How can I keep records of emails that are sent from within the case record.Currently none of the emails are being added to the record. Am I missing something? Do i need to use apex to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to track email send for an object. But in Email Log section you can see how many outbound emails has been send.

Please check the link below -

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000213985&type=1

You might get some clue.